# Chave Composta JPA+EclipseLink com Objeto

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse-link

Estou criando uma classe de estoques onde a chave da tabela será o código do produto+local, isso para que o sistema possa controlar vários estoques do mesmo produto em locais diferentes.
Criei uma entidade chamada Estoques e outra chamada EstoquesPK ( Esta para armazenar a chave composta), porem ao executar esta retornando o erro abaixo.

**The mapping [B2_COD] from the embedded ID class [class entidades.EstoquesPK] is an invalid mapping for this class. An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [id] from the source [class entidades.Estoques]) can only contain basic mappings. Either remove the non basic mapping or change the embedded ID specification on the source to be embedded.**

Segue abaixo a chave composta

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;


@Embeddable
public class EstoquesPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -637018809489152388L;
    
    private Produtos B2_COD;
    @Column(length = 2)
    private String B2_LOCAL;

    public Produtos getB2_COD() {
        return B2_COD;
    }

    public void setB2_COD(Produtos b2_COD) {
        B2_COD = b2_COD;
    }

    public String getB2_LOCAL() {
        return B2_LOCAL;
    }

    public void setB2_LOCAL(String b2_LOCAL) {
        B2_LOCAL = b2_LOCAL;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((B2_COD == null) ? 0 : B2_COD.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((B2_LOCAL == null) ? 0 : B2_LOCAL.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EstoquesPK other = (EstoquesPK) obj;
        if (B2_COD == null) {
            if (other.B2_COD != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!B2_COD.equals(other.B2_COD))
            return false;
        if (B2_LOCAL == null) {
            if (other.B2_LOCAL != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!B2_LOCAL.equals(other.B2_LOCAL))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    

}
```

Segue Entidade que usa a chave composta

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Estoques implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5999236902534007386L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EstoquesPK id;

    private int B2_QATU;

    private double B2_CMUNIT;

    private double B2_VATU;

    private double B2_QFIM;

    private double B2_VFIM;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String B2_DTFECHA;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String B2_DTULTINV;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String B2_DTCADASTRO;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String B2_ALTERA;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String B2_DTINTEG;

    public EstoquesPK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescric() {
        return id.getB2_COD().getB1_DESC();
    }
    
    
    
    public void setId(EstoquesPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getB2_QATU() {
        return B2_QATU;
    }
    
    public void setB2_QATU(int b2_QATU) {
        B2_QATU = b2_QATU;
    }

    public double getB2_CMUNIT() {
        return B2_CMUNIT;
    }

    public void setB2_CMUNIT(double b2_CMUNIT) {
        B2_CMUNIT = b2_CMUNIT;
    }

    public double getB2_VATU() {
        return B2_VATU;
    }

    public void setB2_VATU(double b2_VATU) {
        B2_VATU = b2_VATU;
    }

    public double getB2_QFIM() {
        return B2_QFIM;
    }

    public void setB2_QFIM(double b2_QFIM) {
        B2_QFIM = b2_QFIM;
    }

    public double getB2_VFIM() {
        return B2_VFIM;
    }

    public void setB2_VFIM(double b2_VFIM) {
        B2_VFIM = b2_VFIM;
    }

    public String getB2_DTFECHA() {
        return B2_DTFECHA;
    }

    public void setB2_DTFECHA(String b2_DTFECHA) {
        B2_DTFECHA = b2_DTFECHA;
    }

    public String getB2_DTULTINV() {
        return B2_DTULTINV;
    }

    public void setB2_DTULTINV(String b2_DTULTINV) {
        B2_DTULTINV = b2_DTULTINV;
    }

    public String getB2_DTCADASTRO() {
        return B2_DTCADASTRO;
    }

    public void setB2_DTCADASTRO(String b2_DTCADASTRO) {
        B2_DTCADASTRO = b2_DTCADASTRO;
    }

    public String getB2_ALTERA() {
        return B2_ALTERA;
    }

    public void setB2_ALTERA(String b2_ALTERA) {
        B2_ALTERA = b2_ALTERA;
    }

    public String getB2_DTINTEG() {
        return B2_DTINTEG;
    }

    public void setB2_DTINTEG(String b2_DTINTEG) {
        B2_DTINTEG = b2_DTINTEG;
    }

}
```

A única coisa que estou usando diferente é que na chave composta o campo B2_COD é um objeto da classe Produtos. Ja tentei fazer este mapeamento de varias maneiras e não obtive sucesso. Por favor se algum puder me ajudar Agradeço.
Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Tem vário problemas aí
O primeiro, a nomenclatura não segue as convenções do Java, mas indo para o problema,

Segundo, você deveria definir um nome significativo para os atributos, diferente da coluna do BD

ex:

```
@Column(name = "B2_QATU")
private String nomeSignificativo;
```

e por fim o problema é que a EstoquesPK não deve conter outros objetos, então você vai resolver declarando assim,

```
@Column(name = "B2_COD")
private String idProduto;
```

e na classe Estoques você pode adicionar uma referência do produto mais ou menos assim

```
@JoinColumn(updatable = false)
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "B2_COD")
private Produto produto
```